# UICollectionView layout change when frame size changes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm working with a `UICollectionView` but I have a weird behaviour.

I want a horizontal scroll, small cell height ( smaller than the `UICollectionView` height). 
Tapping a button will increase even more the height of the collection.

The problem is that the layout of my cells is changing also. 
I want the collection view height to increase with the cells staying in the same position.
Here attached 2 screen captures (before/after button touched).
Here is my code:

```
var smallLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
smallLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
var itemHeight = 100
smallLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(150, itemHeight);
var bottomDist:CGFloat = 1
var topDist = collHeight - itemHeight - bottomDist
smallLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topDist, left: 2, bottom: bottomDist, right: 2)
smallLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 15
smallLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
```

So, when touching the button I have the following code:

```
let viewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)
let viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)
var collHeight:CGFloat = 600
var collYPosition = viewHeight-CGFloat(collHeight)-20
var rect = CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(collYPosition), CGFloat(viewWidth), CGFloat(collHeight))
dishCollectionView.frame = rect
```

So, I cannot understand why my layout is changing.

I want to have my cell at the bottom.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps if you reset the top of your `sectionInset` to accommodate for the additional height, i.e. an updated `topDist` calculation.  Try adding something like this to you on touch code:

```
var bottomDist:CGFloat = 1
var topDist = collHeight - itemHeight - bottomDist
dishCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topDist, left: 2, bottom: bottomDist, right: 2)
dishCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```